# Gostaria de pegar apenas o horário dessa string usando javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Gostaria de pegar apenas o horário dessa *string* usando javascript

```
2022-04-29T19:56:36.327Z
```

Ficaria apenas `19:56`

Comment: Veja **slice()** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice, **substr()** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr e **substring()** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: Eu converteria para `Date` e pegaria as informações desse objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu formato de data (2022-04-29T19:56:36.327Z) é ISO 8601, sendo assim, pode utilizar a API de `Date`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse.

---

```js
let d = new Date("2022-04-29T19:56:36.327Z")
console.log(d.getUTCHours()+":"+d.getUTCMinutes())
```

Note que a sua data atual é UTC, por isso usa o `getUTC*`.